# How to pass an object as an attribute of another object using jersey(jax-rs) client in a post request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I wan't to pass an object which consist of another object as it's one attribute,so how to achieve this?

Ex:

Class

```
public class CustomerProduct{

         private int customerId;
         private String customerName;
         private Product product;

        //Constructors and getters setters


         } 
         Product p1 = new Product(with required args);
         CustomerProduct obj = new CustomerProduct(1,"John",p1);
```

Now I need to pass the obj to the rest API post method as an object[Here rest API is implemented by spring boot]

`Response response1 =client.target(endPointUrl).request().post(Entity.json(obj));`

Here with the aid of this method only the customerId and customerName will be receive by the rest API and the Product object will be get as null.

Sample code of rest API method

```
@PostMapping("/customer-product")
   public void sampleControllerMethod(@RequestBody CUstomerProductDTO customerProductDTO){
        customerProductService.methodA(customerProductDTO);

   }
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In here What I did to solve this issue was using the attributes that I needed in product class as attributes in CustomerProduct class.

Example:

```
public class CustomerProduct{

    private int customerId;
    private String customerName;

    //Using the attributes in Product class as attributes in CustomerProduct class

    private String productName;
    private String productPrice;
    //Likewise I used product object attributes inside the CustomerProduct class 

    //Overloaded constructors and getters setters

}
```

So after that  I passed the object of CustomerProduct as a single object to the post method of Rest API using jax-rs like below.

```
 CustomerProduct obj = new CustomerProduct(args);

 Response response1 =client.target(endPointUrl).request().post(Entity.json(obj));
```